# How can i get data from firestore to usermodel in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, model

I want data from firestore databse (collection("userdata").doc(docId)) from here i have my doc id as the uid of the current user so i just want the data inside that doc for example name dp bio etc. but all the methods i found online are not working i dont know why if you know the solution please help i am tired now as i am stuck here for 3 days now.

here is my UserModel.dart

```
class UserModel {
  String? name;
  String? bio;
  String? dpUrl;
  String? email;
  String? uid;
  DateTime? time;
  List<String>? followers;
  List<String>? followings;

  UserModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.bio,
    required this.dpUrl,
    required this.email,
    required this.uid,
    required this.time,
    required this.followers,
    required this.followings,
  });

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    dpUrl = json['dpUrl'];
    email = json['email'];
    uid = json['uid'];
    time = json['time'];
    followers = json['followers'].cast<String>();
    followings = json['followings'].cast<String>();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['bio'] = bio;
    data['dpUrl'] = dpUrl;
    data['email'] = email;
    data['uid'] = uid;
    data['time'] = time;
    data['followers'] = followers;
    data['followings'] = followings;
    return data;
  }
}
```

i had tried these solutions and now of them are working.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_say/model/user_model.dart';

class Database {
  final String? uid;

  Database({required this.uid});

  final userdataRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userdata');

  // Stream<UserModel?> get getUserData {
  //   return userdataRef.doc(uid).snapshots().map(
  //       (DocumentSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snapshot) =>
  //           UserModel.fromFirestore(snapshot.data()!));
  // }

  // Stream<UserModel> get getData {
  //   return userdataRef.doc(uid).snapshots().map(
  //       (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) =>
  //           UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
  // }

  // Stream<UserModel> get data {
  //   return userdataRef.doc(uid).snapshots().map(
  //         (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> event) =>
  //             UserModel.fromJson(event.data()!),
  //       );
  // }

  // Future<UserModel?> readUser() async {
  //   final docUser = userdataRef.doc(uid);
  //   final snapshot = await docUser.get();

  //   if (snapshot.exists) {
  //     return UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
  //   }
  //   return null;
  // }
}
```

all codes in comments are tested and found not working.

I'm trying to get the data in ProfilePage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_say/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_say/services/database.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  const ProfilePage({
    super.key,
    required this.uid,
  });

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(
      future: Database(uid: widget.uid).readUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text(
                'ERROR'), // While running the app in my phy device i get this error.
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        var data = snapshot.data!;
        return SafeArea(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Name - ${data.name}'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[Error from my physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JmMw.png)

[Reason for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNFnB.png)

Comment: What is not working? What do you get when you run these functions

Comment: Last one should work, It is correct

Comment: While running all I was getting error and that error was if(snapshots.hasError) { return const Text('Error'), }

Comment: what was the error

Comment: Wait let me add the ss

Comment: check now i added the where i am getting error

Comment: inside snapshot.hasError condition add this print(snapshot.error); and get the specific error

Comment: Hi I have added the ss how can I fix this ?

Comment: Anyways I got the fix thankyou for your response I just had to add .toDate(); in my usermodel